# Java Jackson update json 2nd value instance in array

Tags: java, json, jackson, nodes, objectmapper

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to go about updating a part of my json. So far I have not found anywhere that shows me how to do this.

For an example, this is what I am needing to update:

```
{
    "lastUpdated": "",
    "firetvs": [
        {
            "name": "lr",
            "ip": "",
            "mac": "",
            "token": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "mbr",
            "ip": "",
            "mac": "",
            "token": ""
        },...ETC....
```

So I am needing to update the data under the

```
"name": "mbr"
 "mac": ""
```

part which I would need to update the mac address to something like:

```
"name": "mbr"
 "mac": "C1:41:Q4:E8:S1:98:V1"
```

I have found code that allows me to update a **standard value** like my **lastUpdated** but not for something that's part of an array:

```
String jsonObject = "{" + 
    "\"lastUpdated\": \"\"," +
    "\"firetvs\": [" +
        "{" +
            "\"name\": \"lr\"," +
            "\"ip\": \"\"," +
            "\"mac\": \"\"," +
            "\"token\": \"\"" +
        "}," +
        "{" +
            "\"name\": \"mbr\"," +
            "\"ip\": \"\"," +
            "\"mac\": \"\"," +
            "\"token\": \"\"" +
        "}" +
    "]" +
"}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode objectNode = null;

try {
    objectNode = objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, ObjectNode.class);
    objectNode.put("lastUpdated", "02-08-2024");
    Log.d("test", objectNode.toPrettyString());
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I did find this:

```
objectNode.with("firetvs").put("mac", "C1:41:Q4:E8:S1:98:V1");
```

But that wont work since its just going to find the first instance of "mac" and update that value instead of updating the 2nd instance of it. And I also get an error of:

> Property 'firetvs' has value that is not of type ObjectNode (but com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode)

So, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: I think this might work for you: 1. use objectNode.get("firetvs") method and cast it to and ArrayNode object. 2. Take take ArrayNode object's second element and cast it back to ObjectNode. 3. You can use the put("mac", "C1:41:Q4:E8:S1:98:V1") method now on the object created in the second point.

Comment: Do you need to put the same mac address to all the elements of the firetvs array or just to specific ones?

Comment: @dani-vta it would be one specific. I have more to the array but shortened it to 2 so that it would not take up so much space in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try JSON library *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
        "\"lastUpdated\": \"\"," +
        "\"firetvs\": [" +
            "{" +
                "\"name\": \"lr\"," +
                "\"ip\": \"\"," +
                "\"mac\": \"\"," +
                "\"token\": \"\"" +
            "}," +
            "{" +
                "\"name\": \"mbr\"," +
                "\"ip\": \"\"," +
                "\"mac\": \"\"," +
                "\"token\": \"\"" +
            "}" +
        "]" +
    "}");
Map<String, JsonNode> params = Map.of(
    "$date", TextNode.valueOf("02-08-2024"),
    "$key", TextNode.valueOf("mbr"),
    "$val", TextNode.valueOf("C1:41:Q4:E8:S1:98:V1")
);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(lastUpdated:$date, firetvs.field(mac:if([name=$key],$val,mac)))", params);
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "lastUpdated" : "02-08-2024",
  "firetvs" : [ {
    "name" : "lr",
    "ip" : "",
    "mac" : "",
    "token" : ""
  }, {
    "name" : "mbr",
    "ip" : "",
    "mac" : "C1:41:Q4:E8:S1:98:V1",
    "token" : ""
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and link Raymond!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the mac address of the `firetvs` elements only under certain conditions, for example that `name` is equals to `mbr`, I'm providing an alternative solution with streams.

Basically, the `firetvs`'s elements are streamed via an `Iterable`, then filtered by keeping only the ones with `mbr` as their `name`, and finally updated with the correct mac address.

In the following sample, I've added only a couple of elements within `firetvs` to not clutter the code. However, here at [oneCompiler](https://onecompiler.com/java/428j9qtkj) I've included more elements showing the desired output.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "    \"lastUpdated\": \"\",\n" +
                "    \"firetvs\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"lr\",\n" +
                "            \"ip\": \"\",\n" +
                "            \"mac\": \"\",\n" +
                "            \"token\": \"\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"mbr\",\n" +
                "            \"ip\": \"\",\n" +
                "            \"mac\": \"\",\n" +
                "            \"token\": \"\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";

        String mac = "C1:41:Q4:E8:S1:98:V1";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode rootNode = objectMapper.readValue(json, ObjectNode.class);
        ArrayNode firetvsNode = (ArrayNode) rootNode.get("firetvs");

        //Creating an Iterable form the Iterator of the firetvs' nodes
        Iterable<JsonNode> iterable = () -> firetvsNode.iterator();

        StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)     //Streaming the firetvs' nodes
                .filter(node -> node.get("name").asText().equals("mbr"))    //Keeping only the elements with mbr as their name
                .forEach(node -> ((ObjectNode) node).put("mac", mac));  //Updating the mac address of each element

        String jsonMacReplaced = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
        System.out.println(jsonMacReplaced);
    }
}
```